# Are Nataraja, Pancha Bhuta Lingas, Mookambika. and Meenakshi mentioned in any scriptures?

Tags: scripture, shiva, devi, reference-request, parvati

Nataraja, the Panchabuta Lingas, Mookambika, and Meenakshi are some well-known deities in South India.

Do any Hindu scriptures mention them?

Comment: Yes. We have Halasya (Alavai Madurai) Mahatmya mentioning Meenakshi. Nataraja is also there in the purana, but I don’t know whether the term ‘Natarajar’ is mentioned. If you want the term then probably we’ll need to find the Pundarikapura (Puliyur Chidambaram) Mahatmya

Comment: But I don't think they are actually Sanskrit scriptures.

Comment: They’re available in Sanskrit as part of the Skanda Purana. Otherwise, by logic, most of the texts that we have today are not entirely original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mookambika is not mentioned in any scripture.

The pancha bhuta lingas are not outlined in detail in any of the Sanskrit scriptures; the idea originates from the Tamil [Tevaram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tevaram).

Meenakshi is mentioned in the [Devi Bhagavata Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57429.html), in a chapter about the sacred places of Devi:

> The great place of Śrī Guhya Kālī, well established in Nepal, and that of **Śrī Mīnākṣī Devī** established in Cīdamvaram.

Shiva-the-dancer is mentioned in scripture, but the epithet 'Nataraja' seems to have been used rarely. One example is in the [Garga Samhita](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/garga-samhita-english/d/doc1123841.html):

> nataṃ kṛtvānana-śataṃ
> sthito 'bhūt kṛṣṇa-sammukhe
> āruhya tat-phaṇi-śataṃ
> maṇi-vṛnda-manoharam
> nanarta naṭavat kṛṣṇo
> naṭa-veṣo manoharaḥ
> gāyan sapta-svarai rāgaṃ
> saṅgitaṃ ca sa-tālakam
> puṣpair deveṣu varṣatsu
> tāṇḍave **naṭa-rāja**-vat
> vādayan sa mudā vīṇā-
> nakadundubhi-veṇukān
>
> When the snake's heads were down, handsome Kṛṣṇa climbed on its hundred jewel-decorated hoods. Singing melodies in the seven-note scale and playing the flute, drum, and vīṇā, as the demigods showered flowers, Kṛṣṇa furiously danced, as does **Lord Śiva, the king of dancers.**
> [2.12.13-15]

Comment: Tevaram is a scripture of Tamil-Saivism, fully citable.  There is an enormous amount of sectarian citations from other South Indian scripture at HSE.  @cdr . Also Mookanbika seems a popular deity who might have a sthala purana, that is scripture too,

Comment: @CDR It look like accepted; but i forget to add "expect Arunachala" in the question. Because, i know that this linga have mentioned in Skanda Purana.

Comment: @Boovanaes - I don't understand, can you please clarify?